# How to only print the 4th link + how to save all the links

Tags: python, string

I have a program that gets links from a HTML source file and I want to make it save all the links in a variable and then print only the 4th link. How would I do that?

The code:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(z["body"], features="lxml")
for tag in soup.find_all("a"):
    links = tag.get("href")
```

Comment: Count the number of newlines, or split at the newlines.

Comment: Is this a string, or a file you're trying to read?

Comment: It's a response in a JSON from a request, not really sure... I'll try what you answered with.

Comment: Updated my answer to address your completely new question...

Answer (score 2):

After you've heavily edited the post and changed the question completely... IIUC:

```
links = [tag.get('href') for tag in soup.find_all("a")]
print(links[3])
```

---

Use [`str.splitlines()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.splitlines)~

Given:

```
text = """user1:hwid
user2:hwid
user3:hwid
user4:hwid
user5:hwid"""
```

Doing:

```
print(text.splitlines()[3])
```

Output:

```
user4:hwid
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative in a specific case would be to select your element directly - You could use `css selectors` more specific a pseudo class `:nth-of-type()` that matches all elements of a given type, based on their position **among a group of siblings**:

```
links = soup.select_one('a:nth-of-type(4)').get("href")
```

##### Example

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = '''
<h2><span>Title1</span></h2>
<p>some text</p>
<a href="1">link 1</a>
<h2><span>Title2</span></h2>
<a href="2">link 2</a>
<p>some text</p>
<a href="3">link 3</a>
<a href="4">link 4</a>
'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

soup.select_one('a:nth-of-type(4)').get("href")
```